# Automatic calling system: "Press star" or "Press asterisk"?

Tags: telephone

I'm not a native English speaker and currently have a task on my desk to translate some texts for an automatic telephone calling system. You know the stuff: *to confirm your request, press one, to cancel, press pound*.

And the question is: **Should I use "star" or "asterisk"**, down left on the keypad, when your computer program talks to someone over phone?

Edit:

The calling system will be addressing both native  English speakers and people who have English as their second or third language.

*Asterisk* is easier to understand in over low-quality telephone connection, but may confuse non-native English speakers.

*Star* is more or less clear to everyone, but may get misheard  as it is only one syllable (especially when the phone connection is suboptimal).

Edit 2:

The system is supposed to give calls to people around the world in case of emergency with system they are responsible for. It allows for translation to any language, but the company running the system will not pay translation for one or two people, so everyone for whom there is no translation will get the call in English.

We use software synthesized voice messages (and not recorded human voice) and so the messages need to be as clear and concise as possible.

Comment: Is your question basically: what is this `*` thing called ?

Comment: @JonW: No, I ask what term to use in this particular situation. I've heard both and I'm not sure which suits better. I'll edit the question to be more clear about it.

Comment: I'd say "every other system I've heard calls it 'star' so I should too." But then I'd be asking "well what do I call `#` then? Number symbol? Hash? Pound?"

Comment: `*` - [snowflake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snowflake) key

Comment: @Niet, Most teleconferencing systems I've used hedge their bets and say "Press the pound or hash sign".  I think this is mainly because in the UK you wouldn't call it 'pound' as that would be ambiguous with the monetary symbol.  I don't know if there are similar ambiguities with 'star' or 'asterisk', but I don't think so.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol: Please press the _jail_ symbol has a nice sounding to it in certain situations, too. As we've been discussing this matter further, we've found, that even in German and Czech the name for the `#` sometimes causes problems and confusion. This makes me wonder whether the button has had any name at all during the design process of the first keypad phone.

Comment: It was only last week I discovered that Americans called # the "pound sign". Very confusing terminology for someone speaking British English where £ is a pound sign. Something to be careful about.

Comment: FYI, *asterisk* in Spanish is *asterisco*, which sounds very similar, so no problem here. On the other hand, we'd have a hard time guessing * as *star*.

Comment: @FranciscoPresencia At least they don't use #poundtag

Comment: @FrancisDavey Actually we rarely call it the "pound sign" in American English. We usually call it the "number sign" or, for teenagers in the Twitter Age, they often incorrectly call it a hashtag. "Hash" and "pound" are much less common, but "pound" is used exclusively in the context of telephony, referring not to the symbol but to the button itself ("press pound"). Since pounds aren't our currency, the term "pounds" makes us think only of "lbs." which is the "symbol" for the measurement of weight in the (stupid) U.S. Customary Unit system.

Comment: "Star" is fine – **asteriskos = "little star" in Greek.**

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Press star.

Asterisk is the correct term, however some people will not know if * or # is an asterisk.

In fact, if they have heard * referred to as 'star' then they might assume that # must be 'asterisk'.

The word 'star' however will allow people to know what button to press, even if they have never heard of the correct terms, as it is a word with much more common usage and understanding.

This is not an English language question, as suggested, as the correct English word would be 'asterisk'.

If you have control over the software behind this, then it would be a good idea to make the system recognise presses of either * or #, in case people press the wrong one (assuming that # does not already have a different purpose).

Comment: Thank you for a very good point about recognizing both * and #, that is a very good idea! Yes, the software is developed in my company and it is actually very easy to add this feature.

Comment: On the other hand, accepting both adds to the public's confusion going forward.

Comment: +1 for accepting both. Despite having no problem understanding the meaning of either word, I find that by the time I finish entering the number the system asked for (and concentrating on making sure I don't get it wrong), entering a voice message, or whatever, I've **forgotten what convention the system I'm communicating with is using** and end up pressing the wrong one, often aborting the whole operation. This is horribly bad UX, and "accept both" is an amazingly simple solution.

Comment: Sorry, Paul, I have to [disagree](http://ux.stackexchange.com/a/62162/40110) on this one.

Comment: Do you have any cite for "Asterisk is the correct term" in the context of telephony? For what it's worth, [the ITU says](https://www.itu.int/rec/dologin_pub.asp?lang=e&id=T-REC-E.161-200102-I!!PDF-E&type=items) "The symbol will be known as the *star* or the equivalent term in other languages".

Comment: Why not meet Paul and Maverick halfway? If `#` is pressed, and it is performing no other function (it isn't, if you were going to map it to the same) then have some other prompt like "Not recognised, did you mean to press the asterisk key?"

Comment: @OllieFord I would not make the process more complicated... Because what are the chances, that the user presses # and expects something else to happen? I would say 95% of the people who press # in this situation want to press * so you should just accept it and go on, without trying to educate your customer

Comment: @Falco If you later add different functionality to `#` it will be confusing (they'll think "why switch? You should've put this new thing on `*`!)

Comment: @OllieFord you have to evaluate what is more important - a good experience now, or possible future use cases? Beacuse if you want more functionality maybe they have to press multiple buttons? So should you now warn them if they press a button twice? And should you give them enough time to press it twice, so they will not be confused about increased waiting times later? - I'd rather later say to them "Press the HASH to do X and press the Star to do Y"

Comment: Knowing what is star and not knowing what is asterisk is specially true for illeterate/ almost analphabet people.

Comment: I'm guilty.  I've many times heard asterisk/pound on the phone, and found myself looking at both. User can easily relate to "start" and make the connection to asterisk. I wonder if pound should be renamed to hash? Most people in the modern world know "hashtag"...

Comment: I think it depends on the field. In computation, it is more appropriate to call it an asterisk, but in mathematics, it is almost always called a star.

Answer (score 30):

The standard term for the `*` key, [per the ITU](https://www.itu.int/rec/dologin_pub.asp?lang=e&id=T-REC-E.161-200102-I!!PDF-E&type=items), is "star".

> 3.2.2 Symbols
>   On the 4 × 3 array, the symbol on the button which is immediately to the left of the button 0 (on the 6 × 2 array, the corresponding button is located below 9, and on the 2 × 6 array to the right of button 5) and which, according to UIT-T Q.23, is used to transmit the frequency pair 941 Hz and 1209 Hz, should have a shape easily identified as the general shape shown in Figure 2.
>
> `*`
>
> T0103190-93
>
> Figure 2/E.161
>
> The symbol will be known as the *star* or the equivalent term in other languages.

Comment: Very nice, thank you for bringing a standard in! The most _in other languages_ part is very helpful as well. I edited the question once more to better explain the system in question (and why your answer should get upvoted as well).

Comment: Per the ITU, # is also called **square**, which I have _never_ heard it called square... ever. Most people call it **hash** or **pound**.

Comment: @smpl: I guess that's where the _other languages_ part comes in. At least in Swedish, * is called the swedish word for star and # is called the swedish word for square. Then again, neither pound nor hash would make any sense in Swedish.

Comment: *In some countries an alternative term (e.g. "hash", "pound" or "number sign") may be necessary for this purpose, particularly where the form in Figure 4 [#] is commonly used, in which case it is useful to select and to recommend a preferred term for consistent use nationally.*

Answer (score 10):

I work for a telephone company, and we often do custom IVR prompts for businesses. As a standard (unless the company asks otherwise), we say "star" and "hash" (for the ***** and **#** keys respectively)

The reasoning for this is to avoid confusion as to which key to press. Often times non-native English speakers (or sometimes even native English speakers) aren't sure what "asterisk" means. The ***** key looks like a star, allowing most people to take an educated guess at which key to press when the prompt says "star."

Often times hash is used to confirm entry of a variable amount of digits, therefore star and hash are rarely used together in the same prompt. This way you can always set up a fool proof method of getting the user to the right place (i.e. say star in the prompt, but route star and hash to the same place)

In general, say ***star***!

Comment: In the context of phones, I've only ever heard `#` referred to as "pound".

Comment: @Keavon Often times Americans will substitute "pound" for the hash key. The practices of this go back to the early 1900s when # was commonly used to substitute "lbs" in trade (i.e. 5 pounds could be written as **5#**.) However, calling **#** "pound" is generally frowned upon in telephony when catering to an international audience.

Comment: @Keavon: I am not an English native speaker, so I doubt I would know whatever a pound would mean on a phone keyboard. For people like me a pound is only '£'.

Comment: @sergiol I wouldn't know that a # looks like the word "hash" either but I was speaking purely of convention. I just meant that I have never, ever heard it called a hash in the context of telephones, only pound.

Comment: In Portuguese we call # 'cardinal' (number of items) in any context, except in music, where we call it 'sustenido' (sharp in English).

Answer (score 2):

1. The best would not to have to announce that the * or # key has to be pressed.
2. There are generally accepted conventions upon the use of the # and * keys.

   - # is associated with "ok", e.g. used to “terminate input” — for example, if the operator has to enter a variable-length sequence of digits, they should terminate it (validate it) with a final #.
   - * is associated with “cancel” or, more broadly, “special function”. For example, terminate current dialog and go up one level in the “dialog tree”. Or if the operator enters a variable-length sequence of digits and terminates it with *, it cancels the entry.
3. Why do you want to use the * or # key? Why not use a plain digit (0..9)? You should probably use # or * only if it is consistent with **convention 2**.
4. You should consider that there are at least two variants of the English language — one spoken by native speakers (the vernacular) and another used by non-native speakers as a quasi-universal language — in America this is frequently called EASL (English As a Second Language). I understand that you want to implement the dialog in this EASL language.
5. From personal experience, I suspect that the more universal EASL terms are “star” and “hash”.

Comment: For most of the English-speaking world, the pound sign is £. Calling the hash a pound is unique to the Americas.

Comment: @TRiG: yes, you are probably right. I edited my answer.

Comment: @BrunoBonnefont, thank you for bringing the convention in. We already have that in mind (although it conflicts with the idea sketched in the accepted answer). As for the target group - that is the main problem. We need to address English and American native speakers _and_ the EASL group. Luckily, your suggestion to use _star_ and _hash_ is congruent with other good answers, which increases the confidence that these are the optimal choices.

Comment: @TRiG How is England "most of the English-speaking world"? Even most of Europe uses euros. Although everyone else uses metric, our stupid system still plagues the whole world so I would think "lbs." is associated with the word "pounds" much more than the currency symbol. Am I correct in thinking this?

Comment: I never said that the UK was most of the English-speaking world (and I *certainly* never said that England is). I did say that most English speakers would never associate the symbol # with the word "pound". I have never seen that used. "Five pound (weight)" is "5 lbs." I have *never* seen "5#". I have seen "#5" used for "number five". In fact, that's the *only* use of the symbol I know. It's called "hash" or "number sign". It is *not* called "pound".

Comment: Further, @Keavon, until very recently, if I saw "5#" used to indicate "5 pound", I would have had no idea at all what was meant. I did know that Americans called it a "pound sign", but I didn't know why, or that they used it in this way. A native English speaker does not have to use a currency called "pound" to know of £ as the pound sign. (Irish pounds and Cypriot pounds are now defunct, but both here and in Cyprus English speakers would still know of £ pound signs. Australia doesn't use pounds, but I'd guess they'd still call £ a pound sign. (Egyptian pounds are still extant.))

Comment: @TRiG I also never knew 5# meant 5 lbs. That isn't the case in America either. Apparently it used to be in the early 1900s but it is **never** used anymore. Until I read the interesting discussions on this question I would have thought 5# meant "number 5" written backwards. I guess we learn something every day!

Answer (score 1):

People have rightly clarified that "pound" for # is pounds weight, not pounds as in money, and that it's not generally understood outside the US (? Canada) - hash is reasonable, and I agree that "square" is very rarely used although that's what the ITU tells us to call it. In the very early days of 12-button keyphones in the UK it was called "gate". That died a quick death! And again, I agree that the answer to the OP's question is that * should be "star" because "asterisk" is less likely to be understood by people for whom English is not their first language, and also 'cos that's what the ITU says.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest: "Press the key called star or asterisk." This is less ambiguous than "Press the star or asterisk key," as the latter could be taken to refer to the 'or' function of two different keys when one isn't sure what the keys are called.

Answer (score 0):

I have to disagree with [Paul S](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/62099/40110).

It is not wise to accept a key that is not the correct key because

1. you will not be able to use that key for any other function and
2. it's confusing.

I especially disagree with the `#` symbol being confused for a **star** or **asterisk**.

The `#` symbol is the [octothorpe](http://www.computerhope.com/jargon/o/octothor.htm),

> which is alternatively referred to as the hash, hash-mark, number, number key, number sign, or a pound (not to be confused with the pounds sterling "£").

Therefore, it makes more sense to just include both names of the `*` symbol in your recording.

You would record something like this:

> *To confirm your request, press the **asterisk** (or **star**) key.*

or

> *To confirm your request, press the **star** (or **asterisk**) key.*

This avoids the confusion by stating both accepted names for the key.

Comment: If you say "or" they may then assume that it accepts both, like in the suggestion Paul S made. They know star means asterisk, but they may think asterisk means pound.

Comment: Possibly, but that would be rare. However, instead of `or` you could say `slash` as in asterisk / star (asterisk slash star)

Comment: When making telephone prompts, typically you want to keep the recording as short and concise as possible to avoid confusion, and to not annoy the user. Most people are able to discern which key on their Touch-Tone™ keypad looks like a star.

Comment: The pound symbol (£) is not unique to pound sterling. It applies to all pounds, such as the Egyptian pound and the now defunct Irish and Cypriot pounds.

Comment: @TRiG - I pulled that from the linked octothorpe.

Comment: @smpl - I agree; I'm simply providing an alternate solution.  I *DO NOT* like using the incorrect `#` key for the correct `*` key, so I thought if we can't use *star* or *asterisk*, just use both.

Comment: @CodeMaverick - it is difficult to translate the parentheses to speech so that the whole sentence is easily comprehensible even if the connection quality is low. We are using a speech synthesis software (and not recorded human voice) which makes this problem even harder.

Comment: I think it is pretty common in UI to accept anything if you know what the user wants. Is it likely the user wants to do anything else by pressing the # Key? It is not a key with any common function, there is no other action connected to it, so there are just two likely possibilities: 1. the user pressed it by accident (this can happen with any key) 2. the user thought it was the right key (star/asterisk) - since it is the only reasonable choice in the UI-Flow, just accept it!

Comment: Octothorp? We should all call it that in recorded messages!

Comment: @Keavon - That would be horrible wouldn't it? lol

Comment: @CodeMaverick No! It would be awesome! It would go well with Octopie. And Octodads. And Octocats!

Comment: @Keavon - Automated System: "Enter your account number and press the octothorpe key!" User: "What the what?!" LoL ... that would be funny.